# Долгая загрузка AAC stream в android

Tags: mediaplayer, android, потоки-данных

Пишу интернет-радио. При использовании потока формата AAC перед проигрыванием возникает большая пауза. Можно ли ее как-нибудь уменьшить? Поток подхватываю при помощи кода:

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rl.PathStream);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(RadioAdapter.this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

...

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
mp.start();     
}
```

Comment: Большая насколько? В буфер пишет, наверно.

Comment: При загрузке mp3 потока секунда, при АСС от 5 секунд. Проверял как на эмуляторе, так и на телефоне с wifi.